# Get text to appear over image

Tags: html, css

I want my text to appear over an image, at the bottom of the image. I can get it to work but when I scale the page, the text moves out of the div (below the image). I want it to stay in the same place when i scale the page.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <img src="images/ct.jpg" class="info-image">
  <p class="HeaderText">Canterbury Tales<p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.info-image {
width:100%;
position:relative;
}

.HeaderText {
position:absolute;
left:35px;
bottom: 10px;
font-size: 3em;
}
```

website: explorecanterbury.co.uk

the div can be found by clicking on canterbury tales building

Comment: Your main issue is that the `.HeaderText` is absolute relative to `.header` and not `.info-image`. all you have to do is give `position:relative;` to `.header`, and `position:absolute;` to `.info-image` & `.HeaderText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems:

- You need to close `<p>` with `</p>`.
- Use `position: relative` on the `.header`.

Like this?

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}
.info-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.HeaderText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="//placehold.it/500" class="info-image">
  <p class="HeaderText">Canterbury Tales</p>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: This does kind of work, but the image isn't responsive anymore

Comment: @user3005003 Lemme check your main page. Where in the URL?

Comment: explorecanterbury.co.uk

Comment: @user3005003 Where there?

Comment: you have to click on the building 'canterbury tale' its in the middle of the map

Comment: @user3005003 Checked it. Looks good for me. In three resolutions, including in my mobile.

Comment: @user3005003 So it is fixed. Working fine. Right?

Comment: wasn't me that downvoted! it seems to be working now, thanks

Comment: @user3005003 I know.

Answer (score -2):

Give the image a lower z-index then the text:

```
.info-image {
width:100%;
position:relative;
z-index: 1;
}

.HeaderText {
position:absolute;
left:35px;
bottom: 10px;
font-size: 3em;
z-index:2;
}
```

If that doesn't work, try giving the image a position of absolute, and the text a position of relative.

Comment: The p tag has a higher z-index by default because it's later in the DOM, z-index has nothing to do with this.